# Merging some array into single array/list in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

How to covert this array (different dimensions numpy),

```
l= (array([0.08]), array([[ 0.56, -0.01, 0.46]), array([[ 0.60], [0.07], [0.03]]), array([[0., 0., 0., 0.]]), array([[0.]]))
```

into a 1D array,

```
l= array([0.08, 0.56, -0.01, 0.60, 0.07, 0.03, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Comment: Numpy has a few related stacking functions. You can read about them in [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `numpy.hstack` with `ravel` to flatten the various dimensions.

```
import numpy as np

l = (np.array([0.08]), np.array([ 0.56, -0.01, 0.46]),
     np.array([[ 0.60], [0.07], [0.03]]), np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0.]]),
     np.array([[0.]]))

res = np.hstack(i.ravel() for i in l)

array([ 0.08,  0.56, -0.01,  0.46,  0.6 ,  0.07,  0.03,  0.  ,  0.  ,
        0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ])
```

---

Or if you want a functional approach:

```
from operator import methodcaller

res = np.hstack(list(map(methodcaller('ravel'), l)))
```